# Use data from a vector of model (with few attributes) without making ARFF file in WEKA API in JAVA

Tags: java, weka

I am trying to prepare some data that I have in two vectors of my model class to train for classification (one for train and the other for test) using WEKA API in java. Is there a way that I can arrange my data in a way so that I don't have to make an *.ARFF file?

My model class consists of six attributes 
L1(String), L2(String), A(double), B(double), C(double), D(double), Station(String)

Each row would look like this where traindata is the vector:

```
for(int i=0; i<traindata.size(); i++) {
    double[] row = new double[] { traindata.get(i).getL1(),traindata.get(i).getL2(),traindata.get(i).getA(), traindata.get(i).getB(), traindata.get(i).getC(), traindata.get(i).getD(), traindata.get(i).getStation() };
}
```

And the vectors are big collection of these.

Can anyone help me on this,please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For training a classifier in Weka you need an `Instances` object. An `Instances` object contains both the structure of your data and each `Instance` of your data.  An ARFF file is a serialized version of Instances object. An `Instance` is simply a structure that holds an example/instance of your data.

So you can create an `Instances` object, fill it with `Instance`s.
Here is a simple code:

```
// create attributes. For nominal attributes list all possible values
ArrayList<Attribute> attributes = new ArrayList<Attribute>();
attributes.add(new Attribute("L1", new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.AsList("L1_val1", "L1_val2", ...)));
attributes.add(new Attribute("L2", new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.AsList("L2_val1", "L2_val2", ...)));
attributes.add(new Attribute("A"));
attributes.add(new Attribute("B"));
attributes.add(new Attribute("C"));
attributes.add(new Attribute("D"));
attributes.add(new Attribute("Station", new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.AsList("S1", "S2", ...)));

//create Instances
Instances ins = new Instances(name, attributes, traindata.size());

//create Instance
for(int i=0; i<traindata.size(); i++) {
    String L1 = traindata.get(i).getL1();
    String L2 = traindata.get(i).getL2();
    String station = traindata.get(i).getStation();

    double[] row = new double[] { 
        attributes.get(0).indexOfValue(L1), //convert string to double - index of L1
        attributes.get(1).indexOfValue(L2), //convert string to double - index of L2
        traindata.get(i).getA(), 
        traindata.get(i).getB(), 
        traindata.get(i).getC(), 
        traindata.get(i).getD(), 
        attributes.get(1).indexOfValue(station), //convert string to double  
     };
    Instance instance = new DenseInstance(weight, row);
    instances.add(instance);
 }

//build classifier
classifier.buildClassifier(instances);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. It worked! I really appreciate it!!

Comment: If it solves your problem, you can accept the answer @ANJANSAPKOTA . See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers